# How to change font color of items in listbox (wpf)

Tags: wpf, colors, listboxitem

I have a listbox which is bounded to an observable collection. The elements in the collection contain a variable called color. My listbox's items are already bounded to the collection, but how do I also bind the items font color to that? I already have a data template which works fine replacing item's name with the color name like this

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myListBox">
        <TextBlock Padding="0,0,10,0" 
    Text="{Binding Path=Color, Mode=Default}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

but I can't seem to find which property I have to set in order to bind the color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which colour you're referring to, but this will set the background and text/foreground colours.

```
<TextBlock Padding="0,0,10,0" 
    Text="{Binding Path=Color, Mode=Default}"
    Background="{Binding myBackgroundColour}"
    Foreground="{Binding myTextColour}"
/>
```

EDIT: dependancy prop -

```
public string Color
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(ColorProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ColorProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Color.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Color", typeof(string), typeof(CLASSNAMEHERE), new UIPropertyMetadata("Black"));
```

Replace CLASSNAMEHERE with the name to the class you're putting it in, ie the viewmodel class or codebehind class name.

use:

```
this.Color = "Yellow";
```

Comment: What exactly is myBackgroundColour/myTextColour?

Comment: They are the properties you want to bind your colour to. As per your example, you can use <TextBlock Padding="0,0,10,0" 
    Text="{Binding Path=Color, Mode=Default}"
    Foreground="{Binding Path=Color}"
/>
 to set the colour of the text and leave the background unset (when the colour is white though...)

Comment: I already this line Foreground="{Binding Path=Color}" but it doesn't work and I don't know why. If I use  Foreground="Yellow" for example it works fine.

Comment: Is the 'Color' property you're binding to a dependency property? Also, what is it's type? ie, string, SolidColorBrush etc ?

Comment: I don't know what a dependency property is but I guess it is not. The color is of type System.Drawing.Color. I just declared it as private Color color; public Color{ get { return color; } };

Comment: See the additional information in the answer. Also, ForegroundColor and indeed, BackgroundColor needs to be a SolidBrushColor, not a color. The reason you can type the string Blue in the XAML and have it work is because of inbuilt converters.

Comment: eek! that should be a SolidColorBrush, not SolidBrushColor!

Answer (score 1):

you can use this resource style

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
        bla bla bla
    </Style>
```